# Access account link vs. password reset flow?

Tags: security, user-interface, authentication, passwords

This is partially a security question and partially a question of user behavior.

Imagine you've forgotten your password to an account that you don't particularly care about. You'd like to log back in, but don't care *enough* to spend time resetting your password. Instead of resetting your password, you're able to request a login link. The link is active for 15 minutes and you're able to use that to access your account without having to reset your password.

I'm wondering what the downsides (security or otherwise) to this approach are. Obviously, if the user doesn't eventually remember their password, they will need to do this every time they want to login. This doesn't sound like best practice imo, but I'm curious about any tangible security concerns this creates.

If my gut is right and this is a bad idea, are there alternatives to this process? My instinct is that the best viable option is optimizing this flow to make it as seamless as possible for users, but that they will ultimately still need to reset their passwords.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious downside to the proposed approach is based around e-mail being an insecure service. [There is a post here that explains this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30087/good-simple-list-of-reasons-that-email-is-inherently-insecure).

Most sites combat the insecurity of e-mail for password resets in a few ways:

1. Notifying the user that the password has been changed.
2. Making the link single use.
3. Validating the user in another way (e.g. are they using a computer they have logged in from before, a location they typically login, password reset questions etc.)

With the login link that you are proposing. If a bad actor can intercept the e-mail they can log in as the user quickly and easily. This is likely to go unnoticed by the user until after the malicious activity has occurred.